# Pandas join values become NaN

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I want to add coordinates to this cities, but the dataframe does not have one..

group_metro_manila = metro_manila.groupby(['City'])[['Price (PHP)', 'Floor_area (sqm)', 'Price Per SQM']].mean().sort_values('Price (PHP)')

So I manually created them...

city_location = pd.DataFrame({
'City': ['Dasmarinas', 'General Trias', 'Imus', 'Las Pinas', 'Makati', 'Mandaluyong','Manila', 'Muntinlupa','Paranaque','Pasay', 'Pasig','Quezon City', 'Silang', 'Taguig'],
'Latitude': [14.2990, 14.3214, 14.4064, 14.4445, 14.5547, 14.5794, 14.5995, 14.4081, 14.4793, 14.5378, 14.5764, 14.6760, 14.2142, 14.5176],
'Longitude': [120.9590, 120.9073, 120.9405, 120.9939, 121.0244, 121.0359, 120.9842, 121.0415, 121.0198, 121.0014, 121.0851, 121.0437, 120.9687, 121.0509]
})

[group_metro_manila](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMDD8.png)

I want to add the city_location latitude and longitude to their designated city
[city_location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3vpc.png)

So what I do is I join city_location to group_metro_manila

merge_df = group_metro_manila.join(city_location[['City','Latitude','Longitude']].set_index('City'), on='City')

but the values becomes NaN

[Join but values becomes NaN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHVxr.png)

can someone enlighten me on how to add columns without making the values NaN?
I am new to pandas and want to become data analyst, please can someone help me correct my code? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `concat` or `merge`

```py
pd.concat([group_metro_manila, city_location.set_index('City')], axis=1)
# or
group_metro_manila.merge(city_location, left_index=True, right_on='City', how='left')
```

Comment: The concat shows the value but it created same total of rows below and put the values there.

The merge only shows the city but the latitude and the longitude values is still NaN.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of your frames has 'City' as a column and other as index. You'll need to either run `.set_index('City')` on the former or (given a recent enough version of pandas) add `on='City'` to `join()` arguments.

Comment: merge_df = group_metro_manila.join(city_location[['City','Latitude','Longitude']].set_index('City'), on='City')

This is the code the do to join city_location to group_metro_manila. And the values become NaN

Answer (score 0):

This code resolved the problem.

```
dataframe = [group_metro_manila_sorted.reset_index(drop=True), city_location_sorted[['Latitude', 'Longitude']]]

concat_df = pd.concat(dataframe, join='inner',axis=1)
```

Reset the index of the first dataframe, then, instead of merge try to use concat and set the `axis=1` so that it will be concatenated horizontally

[image: concat_df]

Thanks to the guys who helped in the comment section.